# ImageCapture poor quality

Tags: javascript, webrtc, mediastream

Hi does anyone know why the photos taken with the ImageCapture api are so bad or how i can fix this?
when i use the takePhoto function it looks like this:
[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruQSn.jpg
(downsampled for upload) but much more grain und way to bright

when i use the grabFrame function (which has a a lower resolution):
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPnN4.jpg]
the image looks normal.

thes images where taken with https://simpl.info/imagecapture/ on an OnePlus6T but other devices i tested have the same problem.

after trying many thing i fixed the focus with applyConstraints on the video track:

```
.applyConstraints({
        focusMode: 'single-shot',
    })
```

but the image still is to bright and has much grain.

i tried setting exposureMode and exposureCompensation but no change at all.

i realy hope anyone can help me with this....

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: sadly not. But its only on do,r android devices